# How to resolve ubuntu hang on boot (brown swirly screen of death?)?

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I am pretty new at ubuntu and linux in general.  I'm configuring a new installation and going ga ga for all nifty effects compiz gives me, and then I think I went one check box too far.  (I enabled reflection and further enabled it for windows..not even sure what that means, but it sounded cool.  My piddly integrated graphics card seems to disagree.)

So my OS froze.  I rebooted and still frozen.  So I rebooted in recovery mode, fixed broken packages, and rebooted yet again.

Now I can log in , but after logging in, all I see is full screen brownish pic that says "ubuntu" in the middle with a bunch of loopy swirls all over the place.  I'm not sure what this means, or what incantation of linux commands I can utter to pass beyond it.  I'm wishfully thinking that if I could get to my desktop in a "safe mode", and disable one or more compiz options, I'd be back in business.  But I'm struggling to figure out how.

Any insights or solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [this thread has the easiest answer](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-help/116239-how-earth-do-you-reset-compiz-defaults-command-line.html) for you.

Just swap on the tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1), login there and run this command

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz
```

after that, logout and jump back to the login screen (Ctrl+Alt+F7) and try logging in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.  It sounds like that will work great. I was actually able to solve it as well by specifying "failsafe GNOME" when I logged in (an option I had missed before).  This allowed me to get to my desktop, and from there I could go into the compiz control panel, and turn off the reflection effects.  When I logged back in under normal GNOME, everything was fine.  BTW, sure enough, re-enabling reflection recreates the visual freeze up.